# PayPal iOS SDK - Display all payment types associated with a registered PayPal account

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk

We're currently using the new PayPal iOS SDK and would like to find out if there is a way to return a list of accounts that are associated to a PayPal account.

Currently when making a payment via PayPal, only the default account is displayed. Customers don't seem to have the option to select a different payment type.

Example:

- A customer has linked their bank account to PayPal (This is their default payment method)
- The same customer also has their credit card added to their PayPal account.

The SDK only returns option #1 but not option #2.

Is there a way to display the full list (i.e. both option #1 & #2) so customers have the option of selecting a different method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

When you use the PayPal iOS SDK for a ["single payment"](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md), the customer will see their "Preferred Payment Method" displayed, along with the standard iOS `>` disclosure indicator. Tapping that row will then produce a list of available payment methods for the customer's account, from which the customer can then choose.

Is this not what you are seeing in your tests?

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm not seeing this. All I see is the default payment option selected with no disclosure indicator. Here is a screen grab of what I'm seeing! <img src=http://imgur.com/3dRk5nS />

Comment: @TJ are you using a [recent version](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/releases) (say, 2.8.x) of the SDK?

Comment: Hi Dave! You were spot on! We're using v2.1.6, which is really old! We'll update it and that should resolve it!

Thanks so much for your help!